# Storing solar panels in direct sun

Tags: solar-cell, short-circuit, solar-energy, storage, panel

What is the best way to store solar panels when not hooked to a charge controller in direct sun?

I was thinking about hooking each panels pos and neg mc4 connectors to itself so it will not be damaged by water. Will this damage the panel?

Comment: I would just leave the connectors open-circuit and cover them with a non-conductive cap--but I'm not an expert in solar panels.

Answer (score 1):

This is call open circuit operation. It's not a big deal, it may reduce the lifetime of the panels more than not having them lit as sunlight degrades everything. The panels voltage increases to max, and convert sunlight into heat, with little consequence.

You should not connect the positive and negative as this produces a short circuit condition and could damage the solar panel

Comment: What's wrong with short-circuiting a solar panel?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to dump most of the panels power right in the area of the connectors. If you have a +100W module, it could generate a significant amount of heat, in a small area.

Comment: If the connectors can't handle the current, then they aren't the correct connectors for normal operation, either. Short-circuit current isn't that much greater than MPP current. And open-circuit or short-circuit, most of the heat is in the solar cells themselves.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the current rating on the connectors, I'm concerned about the amount of heat generated by the short circuit connection and the proximity to the solar panel if shorted directly together